# How do I pipe into a third process?

Tags: c, unix, system

This is what my code looks like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

char* reverseString(char*);

int main(void)
{
    pid_t id;
    int fd[2], nbytes;
    char string[80];
    char readbuffer[80];
    char* reversed;
    pipe(fd);

    if((id = fork()) == -1)
    {
        perror("fork");
        exit(1);
    }
    if(id != 0)
    {
        close(fd[0]);
        printf("PARENT\n--------------------\n");
        // printf("fork: %d\n", id);
        printf("my pid is %d\n", getpid());
        // printf("my parent's pid is %d\n", getppid());
        printf("enter string: ");
        scanf("%s", string);
        write(fd[1], string, (strlen(string)+1));

    }
    else
    {
        close(fd[1]);
        printf("CHILD\n--------------------\n");
        // printf("fork: %d\n", id);
        printf("my pid is %d\n", getpid());
        // printf("my parent's pid is %d\n", getppid());
        nbytes = read(fd[0], readbuffer, sizeof(readbuffer));
        printf("Received string: %s\n", readbuffer);
        reversed = reverseString(readbuffer);
        printf("Reversed string: %s\n", reversed);

        pid_t id2;
        int fd2[2];
        char readbuffer2[80];

        pipe(fd2);

        if((id2 = fork()) != 0)
        {
            close(fd2[0]);
            printf("My pid: %d\n", getpid());
            write(fd2[1], reversed, (strlen(reversed)+1));
        }
        else
        {
            close(fd2[1]);
            printf("My Child's PID: %d\n", getpid());
            nbytes = read(fd2[0], readbuffer2, sizeof(readbuffer2));
            printf("Received string2: %s\n", readbuffer2);
        }

    }
    return (0);
}

char* reverseString(char* str)
{
    char reversed[80];
    int n = strlen(str);
    for(int i = n - 1, j = 0; i >= 0; i--, j++)
        reversed[j] = str[i];
    reversed[n] = '\0';
    return reversed;
}
```

I'm trying to pipe the reversed string into the third process forked in the second process, but it is not showing up.

Also, when I do `scanf` after enter, the printing keeps going until the child part is printed, then I enter the string. How do I keep it from printing everything. It looks like this:

```
PARENT
--------------------
my pid is 821
enter string: CHILD
--------------------
my pid is 822
$
```

Comment: In the child, put the printfs after the `read`, so that the child waits for input before printing anything.

Comment: thanks @user3386109 that fixed it!

Comment: there are a couple of problems in the code.  1) Which your compiler should have told you about the problem of returned a pointer to a char array that is in the stack in the `reversestring()` function (so effectively that char array is out-of-scope/nolonger exists when the function exits) 2) the second call to `fork()` assumes the call was successful.  That is never a good idea to assume a call to a system function is successful.

Comment: this line: `scanf("%s", string);` does not limit the number of characters the user can entered, so the user can overrun the input buffer `string`, resulting in undefined behaviour, and can lead to a seg fault event.   Also in the `reverseString()` function an assumption (not a safe assumption) that the passed in string is less than 80 characters. Suggest: scanf("%79s", string); where 79 to allow for `scanf()` appending a NUL byte to characters input via a '%s' format specifier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `reverseString` function you are returning the array address which is an automatic local variable. Such variables gets destroyed when the function returns.

```
char* reverseString(char* str)
{
    char reversed[80];
    // local array, cannot use it after the function returns
```

---

Either use `malloc()` to allocate memory which will be preserved in between function calls, or reverse the string inplace.